# Use AppRTC 1:multi video chat on android

Tags: android

recently I use AppRTC `https://github.com/njovy/AppRTCDemo` this link

but this only 1:1 video chat . AppRTC is use room

if during 1:1 communication, 1 use connect communication room, 
`room full message`

I want 1:n , in other words 1:multi video chat

I try search google, but not found hint

if you know AppRTC multi video chat, please advice for me

thanks